# Storing Django translations in a database

Tags: django, heroku, translation

I am working on a Django application which is going to be deployed to Heroku (on their Cedar stack). A limitation of this is that we cannot write to disk. However, Django translations reside in .po files, and therefore the client will be unable to change the translations on the live site without involving a developer (which is not ideal).

The alternative solution therefore seems to be to store the translations in either an RDBMS, Mongo, Redis etc etc.

Is there any sensible way of achieving this? Is it even a good idea? (I wouldn't want to hit the DB for every translation!)

**Edit:** There seem to be lots of Django apps out there for translating text which is stored in a DB, but not for actually storing the translations themselves in a DB.

Comment: tell me is it necessary to save the translations in db?

Answer (score 0):

What I think about Django translations and translations stored in the files in general - this is for the parts which will not change and is not dynamic. Like constants you have in the website. And if you have dynamic text, which could be and must be edited when the website is running - I would say this is the same thing as normal content (blog entry, comments and so on).

So you can just develop simple module "site parts", with the template tag, which will grab the right thing for you from DB. Like from template you can call { get_site_part example }. And then you can edit those parts from admin interface.

I would not recommend to store dynamic content to the system files. If you worry about hitting database every time you need this - then caching should help here also you can develop smart template tag and grab all the site parts you need in one query. Then it will be nothing different from just simply loading blog entry or the comment for it.

Maybe I'm wrong, so this is just my 2c on this topic :)

Ignas

Comment: Hi Ignas, thank you very much. From looking around it seems that what I am looking for hasn't really been done. I think this is an odd position to be in as it is a smaller app, but writing to disk is not on the cards, and neither is requiring developers to put new translations live.